# do magnetic fields affects wifi signals?

Tags: passive-networks

I have note 4 and I  have putted magnetic cover on it, and now sometimes if signals are low then if I put cover off then I can use my wifi connection and if I keep cover on it then it stops working. Do magnetic field really affects wifi signals?
hope I will get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: The Answer is no. Magnets do not affect electromagnetic waves

Comment: The trouble with this being marked as a duplicate is that the original questioner checked out the recommendations in an answer and found that small magnets (ferromagnetic material presumably) didn't affect performance WHILST in this question, the material clearly does affect wifi performance. Do duplicates get deleted I suppose I'm asking? I've voted to re-open btw.

Comment: @Andyaka  The StackExchange automatic cleanup script doesn't delete questions that were closed as duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Magnetic fields do not, but it is possible that the metal in the magnets is changing the antenna characteristics or blocking the signal.

Answer (score 1):

An antenna needs to optimize its physical length to maximize the signal at the particular frequency it wants to receive or transmit at. Usually, for a quarter wave antenna the length is approximately one-quarter the wavelength of the signal where wavelength = velocity / frequency

Now, going back to basic physics, the velocity of light (or an electromagnetic wave) is determined by the permeability and permittivity of free-space or the medium it travels in i.e.

c (in free spece) = \$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon_0 \mu_0}}\$

If you have a ferrite material around the antenna (whether magnetized or not), the permeability around the antenna can be vastly different and this affects the physics and makes the speed of an electromagnetic wave smaller than it is in free space.

A smaller velocity means a shorter wavelength and suddenly, what you thought was a quarter wave antenna is now much bigger electically and doesn't work as well.

There can be other problems too. The interface of a slower EM wave (in the medium it is travelling in) to the free space medium *can* create vast losses of energy too. I'm not saying these will be as vast as a low frequency EM wave breaking thru the surface of a pool of water (in the realms of 60dB) but it's something else to consider as a potential to reduce the signal.